# Is there a word to refer to people who likes gossip?

Tags: word-request

In Portuguese we have the word 'fofoqueira' to refer to a person who likes gossips and/or is constantly gossiping about other people.

Google suggest `gossip girl` but that does not sound right.

Is there a word in english for that kind of people?

Comment: Yes - simply _a gossip_. The verb comes from the noun.

Comment: a gossip? She is a gossip?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fun example of how English parts of speech can be malleable.

We start with the uncountable noun “gossip”.

The expression “to like gossip” or “to share gossip” gets so common that the noun created a new verb “to gossip”.

Normally, a person who *verb*s is called a *verb*er: “a gossiper”. The new verb has in turn created a new noun.

But since the original noun was uncountable and the new one is countable, we can be lazy and simplify “a gossiper” to “a gossip”, and now the original noun has gained a new use and meaning.

Comment: Oddly enough, the etymological chain was exactly the reverse of that.  A "gossip" as a person goes back to the 11th century, it became a verb in the 17th, and was only applied to what was produced by the act of gossiping in the 19th.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Ah, well, it’s the same idea.

Comment: brilliant, thanks!!!

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make the answer less valid.  It's just trivia

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being a **gossip**, such a person can also be called a **gossip-monger** or **busybody**:

gossipmonger (n):
disapproving : a person who enjoys talking about other people's private lives
([merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gossipmonger))